# What is an Etienne Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

*Major Edit*: I have changed the examples of Etienne Words to make it easier.  The previous examples no longer provide any useful information. The underlying theme of Etienne Words is still the same, but the exact procedure for defining them changed slightly to make it easier.

---

*This puzzle is based off the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) and [What is a Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20phrase%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) and their spin-off [What is a Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) series.*

---

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it an Etienne Word™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

[image]

These are not the only examples of Etienne Words™, more can be found.

Hint #1

> No Etienne Words *can* begin with the letter "Z"

Hint #2

> No Etienne Words *do* begin with the letter "J"

Hint #3

> The original name for these words was going to be “Linotype Words.”

Hint #4

> `if (word_val[counter] <= word_val[len(word_val)-1]): word_val.pop(counter); word_val.pop(len(word)-1)`

Comment: must the font be kept to serve its purpose?

Comment: The font does not matter

Comment: In French the meaning of the name Etienne is "Crown" (if that somehow helps).

Comment: Still trying to figure out what or if it's significant, but if it helps anyone try looking at the parts of speech?

Comment: Not sure of the rule yet, but I noticed that ROT13(Gunangbybtl vf gur fpvragvsvp fghql bs qrngu, juvyr Rfpungbybtl vf gur gurbybtvpny fghql bs qrngu (va gur fbeg bs raq bs gur jbeyq frafr). Guvf znxrf zr guvax gung Rgvraar Jbeqf unir fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu n pbapergr vqrn juvyr Aba Rgvraar Jbeqf ner zber nofgenpg. Whfg n gubhtug gubhtu)

Comment: ROT13(N ybg bs gur Rgvraar Jbeqf raq va "vat" juvyr abar bs gur Aba-Rgvraar Jbeqf qb. Abg gur ehyr, ohg znlor cneg bs vg?)

Comment: Maybe the pattern is related to the alphabet using frequency?
Due to each alphabet position arrangement on Linotype keyboard is based on it.

Comment: Getting very close @Conifers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Etienne Words are

> words where the score of each letter in the first half is less than the letter that is at the opposite end of the word. The score of a letter is given by its frequency in the English language (as expressed by its position on [the Linotype keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linotype_machine#/media/File:ClavierLinotype_20041006-163300.jpg)), with high frequency giving a lower score.
>
>  For the word "AFTERGLOWS", which is an Etienne Word, we have A < S, F < W, T < O, E < L, R < G.
>
>  For the word "ETHICS", which isn't an Etienne Word, we have E < S, T < C, **H > I**.

For the hints:

1:

> "Z" has the highest score, so no opposite letter can have a higher score.

2:

> I couldn't get this one to fit. In [this list of 466k words](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt), the following both started with "J" and are Etienne Words: JASZ, JAZZ, JEAZ, JERZ, JEUX, JEUZ, JINX

3:

> The Linotype keyboard arranges letters by their frequency in the English language. This is used as the ranking system.

4:

> This is essentially just the explanation in code form.

Comment: If a high frequency gives letters a low score, then O < F and "AFTERGLOW" is not an Etienne Word anymore.

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt Right, my bad - I intended to write "AFTERGLOWS". "AFTERGLOW" isn't an Etienne Word, as you point out.

Comment: But what about "JAZZ" ? J < Z and A < Z so it would be an Etienne Word but the second hint says that no Etienne Word *do* begin with J

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt Hmm yeah, there seems to be some words that violate hint 2. "JAZZ" and "JINX" are the two actual words I could find.

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt, the other criteria for an Etienne word is that they had to be greater than 4 letters.  The French name Etienne means "crown" which is 5 letters.  Therefore, the minimum word had to be five letters.

Comment: And this is spot on!  Congratulations,  @Birjolaxew

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer.

"Etienne" words are:

> Determined by the position of their letters on a Linotype keyboard like so:
>
>  ESCVX
>  THMBZ
>  ARFG
>  ODWK
>  ILYQ
>  NUPJ

"Etienne" seems to be a reference to:

> The first 6 letters running downwards on a Linotype keyboard are ETAOIN. Letters to the left of this keyboard are also the *most frequently used*.

Comment: how about the word 'zen'?

Comment: @elias I'm testing my answer our and finding other anomalies too... its a WIP

Comment: I don't think I fully understand this. Why is GEARBOX an Etienne word while ETHICS is not?

Comment: @hexomino it isn't. My answer is wrong, I thought I saw a pattern.

Comment: You’re right about the reference. Now just figure out how it’s implemented!